# dust-linkedin browser vs node rendering: object[property] instead of object.property

Tags: node.js, express, linkedin-api, dust.js

I'm playing with dust examples on dust test page http://linkedin.github.com/dustjs/test/test.html and in the same time in node.js (0.8.15), express.js(3.0.4), consolidate(0.0.5), dust-linkedin(1.1.1).

If I execute my template on dust test page (see link at the top) it works well:

```
<a href="/en/subjects/subject-1-page-id">subject 1 title en</a>
```

It renders **subject 1 title en**

If I execute my templte on node/express/consolidate/dust is shows:

```
<a href="/en/subjects/subject-2-page-id">{locale[lang].title}</a>
```

It renders **{locale[lang].title}**

here is my template:

```
{#subjects lang=language}
<div>
    <img src="/files/subjects/{logo}" />
    <div>
        <a href="/{lang}/subjects/{pageId}">{locale[lang].title}</a>
    </div>
</div>
{~n}
{/subjects}
```

here is my JSON object:

```
{
    language: 'en',
    subjects: [
        { 
            logo: 'subject1.jpg', 
            pageId: 'subject-1-page-id', 
            locale: { 
                en: { title: 'subject 1 title en' }, 
                fr: { title: 'subject 1 title fr' },
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

here is rendered template from dust test site:

```
<div>
    <img src="/files/subjects/subject1.jpg" />
    <div>
        <a href="/en/subjects/subject-1-page-id">subject 1 title en</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is rendered templete from node/express/consolidate/dust-linkedin

```
<div>
    <img src="/files/subjects/subject1.jpg" />
    <div >
        <a href="/en/subjects/subject-1-page-id">{locale[lang].title}</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is the part of compiled template from dust test page (see link at the top):

```
.write("\">").reference(ctx.getPath(false, ["locale", ctx.get("lang"), "title"]), ctx, "h").write("</a></div></div>\n");
```

and here is the part compiled on server when I'm using **{locale[lang].title}**.

```
.write("\">{locale[lang].title}</a></div></div>\n");
```

and here is the part compiled on server when I'm using **{locale.en.title}**

```
.write("\">").reference(ctx.getPath(false, ["locale", "en", "title"]), ctx, "h").write("</a></div></div>\n");
```

If I try to render **{locale.en.title}** on node - it works.

Please note **lang** variable always works in the <a href='/**en**/ ...> link

And my question is : why in browser dust parse my path well, but on node doesn't work?
Or, how to render object using 'array-like' key access

Comment: whtat exactly is the problem?

Comment: The problem is :  

why in browser dust-linkedin can process object[property] as template param, but can't process it in node?  

why node compiled template and browser compiled are different ?  

never mind, after I finished my node test between dot, jsRender and dust-linkedin I just dropped the last template engine because it's 10 times slower than dot and jsRender.  
  
  
If Linkedin reworks their engine again using dot or jsRender they will reduce the electricity bill with 90% :)

Comment: P.S.  
Any chances those "two spaces at the end of row" start working ?